# js input type=file/image click not working on chrome, Oct 2022

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
<img src="./images/sendimage.svg" class="sendimage" 
      @click="trigger_img"/>

<input 
    style="display:none" 
    :id="img_input_key" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

this used to work, if i want to trigger file upload behavior in chrome. but it's disabled now? am i getting it wrong or something, can someone explain, if this is going to be disabled in all major browsers? or is it just a bug? what will happen in mobile web?

Oct 11, 2022, Safari still supports this clicking ability.

don't mind the framework, i'm using Vue 2.6, but should not have anything to do with the problem

Comment: The concept seems to still work. (I'm using Firefox.) What is the code for your function `trigger_img`?

Comment: i'm sure code is just fine, grabbing the id and .click()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem
I just re open and it work!
Shut down Chrome completely and turn it back on

Comment: lol i tried everything BUT restarting the browser. thanks a lot!!

Comment: Same, I suspect a Chrome auto-update broke something. Restart worked.

Comment: It was the same for me. I had an auto-update waiting for restart